# Aspose PDF viewer

Tags: wpf, aspose.pdf

I am using the Aspose PDF tools and have successfully got it to print the pdf which is great, but ideally I want to be able to add a wpf control to display this as well.

I would have assumed that the `PdfViewer` class would have something, but I can't tell.

So far I have needed to use a different control `MoonPdfPanel` which is annoying as I would have preferred 1 tool to do both jobs.

Does anyone know of a control I can use to hook into the aspose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We have developed an HTML5 PDF Editor application using Aspose.Pdf for .NET API which you can use in your application as a PDF Viewer as well. You can get the details and complete source code [here](https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.PDF-for-.NET/tree/master/Showcases/HTML5_PDF_Editor_by_Aspose_Pdf_NET). You can use the source code to edit the viewer as per your requirement.

P.S. I am working as social media developer at Aspose.

Comment: The link is broken : here is a good one : https://github.com/aspose-pdf/Aspose.PDF-for-.NET/tree/master/Showcases/HTML5_PDF_Editor_by_Aspose_Pdf_NET

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are interesting in viewing the PDF file, you may convert the file to HTML and display it using an IFrame in your application. I have developed a sample application which performs different operations including viewing a PDF file in IFrame. [Download it](http://goo.gl/ZBmbdm) and try it at your end. Another option is that you can convert the PDF file to images and display in Imageviewer in your application (Code is available in the above application).

P.S. I am working as social media developer at Aspose.

Comment: Thanks, but ideally I wanted to use the inbuilt functions, I have left it as is for now, but if Aspose ever introduces a viewer then I will definitely look at using that